# Textarea ignoring multiple line breaks at beginning

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline, line-breaks

I have a form that populates itself from a database. I have checked all the data being retrieved and am confident it is correct.

One of my fields returns text with **two** line breaks at the beginning of it. When I `echo` the text, it shows these two line breaks, however, if I echo the text in a `textarea`, it ignores one of the line breaks...

Consider this:

```
$data['field'] = "\n\nTest";

// This shows two line breaks in the code
echo $data['field'];

// This shows two line breaks in the code, but only displays one in the textarea
echo '<textarea>'.$data['field'].'</textarea>'
```

Is this because the following are the same:

```
<textarea>
    Value Here
</textarea>

<textarea>Value Here</textarea>
```

If so, how can I get around this? Should I just add a line break to any data that starts with a line break?

Comment: Okay Ben, I have deleted the answer, now when it was turning out to be incorrect and / or didnt help you out. Sorry to take your time :( Good luck with your project!

Comment: @davidkonrad Don't apologize! You were very helpful :-D. Thank you for your time in answering the question!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had almost the same problem and wasn't able to reproduce it first but later I figured out the reason: after minifying the HTML, every `textarea` will be displayed in one line. There seems to be a difference.

```
<textarea>Value here</textarea>
```

- You should consider the difference between raw and minified HTML.
- If you're using an WYSIWYG-Editor (e.g. TinyMCE), try it without.

If nothing helps, I'd add a line-break at the beginning - as you already mentioned. Feels a little dirty, unfortunately.

Comment: I have researched this further an am now absolutely certain it is because the two examples I gave are exactly the same. As the value of a textarea can be on a separate line to the tags, the first line break is ignored... Therefore, you are correct in that the only possible solution (I can see) is to add an additional line break to all textarea entries. Not a nice fix!! :-(

Answer (score 0):

(I know it's an oldie, but I came across this question when searching for a solution to a similar problem, so here's my solution)

The problem is not with *multiple* line breaks. The problem is with a line break at the beginning of a textarea, which is ignored.

So, before populating the textarea with value from the database, I check if there is a linebreak at the beginning, and if so - I add another one. 
This way I have 2 line breaks instead of one. The first one is ignored, but the second one is showing.

```
$text_val = $data['field'];
$pos = strpos($text_val, chr(10));
if ($pos==0) $text_val = chr(10) . $text_val;
echo "<textarea>$text_val</textarea>";
```